# Add image in the message box (UIAlertController)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, messagebox, uialertcontroller

I'm using `UIAlertController()` how can I add just **title and image** in the my message box like this:

[image]

Comment: Based on the answer and comments attached, it sounds (to me anyways) like you are headed down a wrong path. In that regard, **why** are you restricted to using a `UIAlertController`? There are other options to (a) present a view with (b) a title and image in (c) a modal way. Maybe you need to explore those options?

Comment: mmmmm so what's the best solve ?? could you post your answer code please ?? @dfd

Comment: Investigate using a presentation controller. You'll be able to (1) create your own view, (2) have it have everything controlled by it's own view controller, (3) animate any way you wish onto the screen, and everything (in my opinion) you are trying to do. You can simply present a view with a checkbox, or you can be so fancy as to have a table view with IAP purchases and restores, along with a tutorial. I thought the answer was as good as you'll get for your specific issue - even thought it states using 15(!) new lines. That's the threshold (for me) to saying *learn* to do a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

Use below code

```
let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
alertMessage .addAction(action)
self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

let xPosition = self.view.frame.origin.x + 80
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "test.png")
alertMessage.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Without "OK" button you cannot to close above `alertMessage.` 
Set xPosition and y of `imageView`and message of `alertMessage` as per your requirement.

Comment: I don't want action just title and image exactly like above picture in my question @NilayShah

Comment: Your solve is in Swift 2, I'm using Swift 3 @NilayShah

Comment: please check updated answer. If you not satisfy then you have to use third party library for develop the same.

Comment: If I used the first method my image it's out from message box and if I used second method show me a big image @NilayShah

Comment: NO. `imageView` you have to add in alertController. And as per `imageView `frame image size will be 100 X 100.

Comment: Mmmmm, do you mean I must use both methods right ?? @NilayShah

Comment: Note: it's possible this will not be accepted by Apple if it's submitted to the App Store given the use of `setValue(_:forKey:)` to change a private property.

Comment: I'm using this code but show me a large image and different color !! my image is a green color but show me blue color @AlexanderWilhelm

Comment: I can close alert message without action (OK) because I  get timer to my alert message previously @shahnilay86

Comment: @user1.develop If you are using timer for close the alert than above is perfect for you. Also do `let action = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: nil)` for hide the **OK** button.

Comment: Thanks @shahnilay86, this solution worked perfect for me.